# Variable substring match between two column

Tags: r, stringr

I have a dataset with 20,000 rows that in its purest form looks like this:

```
    v1                   v2
1   Case 1 (A v. B)      A v. B 
2   Case 2 (A v. C)      A v. B 
3   Case 2 (A v. C)      C v. B 
4   Case 4 (X v. Z)      X v. Z 
5   Case 5 (B v. A)      A v. B 
6   Case 6 (X v. A)      X v. A 
7   Case 6 (X v. A)      A v. X 
...
```

...except there are n-many variations of  **v1, v2** (actually around ~150, but still too many to list).

I want to return a third column **v3** containing a logical indicator of whether any substring of **v1** matches the string in **v2**.

```
    v1                   v2           v3
1   Case 1 (A v. B)      A v. B       TRUE
2   Case 2 (A v. C)      A v. B       FALSE
3   Case 2 (A v. C)      C v. B       FALSE
4   Case 4 (X v. Z)      X v. Z       TRUE
5   Case 5 (B v. A)      A v. B       FALSE
6   Case 6 (X v. A)      X v. A       TRUE
7   Case 6 (X v. A)      A v. X       FALSE
```

I've been playing around with something like this, which I think is on the right track:

```
library(stringr)
x$v3 <- with(x, str_detect(v1, v2))
```

I'd be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction to a solution/workaround.

MWE shows that my str_detect() technique does not work:

```
x <- structure(list(v1 = c("Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation", 
                          "Application of the International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination Georgia  v  Russian Federation"
), v2 = c("Georgia v Russian Federation", " Ethiopia v South Africa Liberia v South Africa", 
             " Cameroon v United Kingdom", " New Zealand v France", " Australia v France", 
             " Nicaragua v United States of America", " Nicaragua v Honduras", 
             " Nauru v Anustralia", " Nnew Zealand v France", " Islamic Republic of Iran v United States of America", 
             " Bosnia and Herzegovina v Serbia and Montenegro", " Spain v Cananda", 
             " Libyan Arab Jamahiriya v United States of America", " Libyan Arab Jamahiriya v United Kingdom", 
             " Democratic Republic of the Congo v Burundi", " Germany v United States of America", 
             " Democratic Republic of the Congo v Belgium", " Liechtenstein v Germany", 
             " Democratic Republic of the Congo v Ugandan", " Democratic Republic of the Congo v Rwandan", 
             " Nicaragua v Colombia", " Djibouti v France", " Georgia v Russian Federation", 
             " Croatia v Serbia", " Mexico v United States of American", " Democratic Republic of the Congo v Rwanda", 
             " Spain v  Canada", " Australia v  France", " New Zealand v France", 
             " New Zealand v France")), .Names = c("v1", "v2"
             ), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grepl` can be used to compare a single value from v2 to possible substrings of v1

You need to apply it for each row separately, so a quick solution can be:
`apply(data.frame(v1,v2),MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) {grepl(x[2],x[1])})`

In case you want to ignore differences in number of spaces (like the in row #1), you can replace the value in x[2] with the appropriate regex using gsub, so `" "` will be replaced with `" *"` to allow multiple spaces.

In that case this apply will work:

`apply(x,MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) {grepl(gsub(" "," *",x[2]),x[1])})`

Comment: I don't think you are right.

v1 in both 1st and 23rd line contains 2 spaces after Georgia and after the "v", it does not contain the double space in v2.

I will add in the answer an explanation about the spaces and how to solve them

Comment: Can you post the function you used here?
And maybe recheck the data you posted?

I created the dataframe you posted in the question and applied the same function and got TRUE on 1 and 23, everything else is false

Comment: I reset my memory and it works - thanks! You saved me a ton of time. Glad the answer was so straightforward. I was also able to implement fuzzy string matching using the agrep() function: apply(x, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) {
  agrepl(gsub(" "," *", x[2]), x[1], max.distance=.25)})